# View is not getting added in the relative layout on button click in the fragment

Tags: android, dynamic, view, fragment, onclicklistener

I am developing an application in which I have to add dynamic views on the button click.
For this,I have used one fragment and a relative layout in my main xml. In fragments xml I have used an add button and on this button click I want to show the view i.e. button,in the relative layout.
here is my code.

[image: the avd view]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/titles"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.sampledynamicview.MenuFragment" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the **fragment** class is

```
Button btnAddButton;
RelativeLayout rl1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment, null);
    btnAddButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    rl1 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
    btnAddButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Button btn = new Button(getActivity());
            btn.setText("Button");
            rl1.addView(btn);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

**menu_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFD3D3D3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the error in **logcat** is

```
09-04 11:42:14.866: E/AndroidRuntime(552): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 11:42:14.866: E/AndroidRuntime(552): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 11:42:14.866: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at com.example.sampledynamicview.MenuFragment$1.onClick(MenuFragment.java:38)
09-04 11:42:14.866: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-04 11:42:14.866: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
09-04 11:42:14.866: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-04 11:42:14.866: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-04 11:42:14.866: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-04 11:42:14.866: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-04 11:42:14.866: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 11:42:14.866: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-04 11:42:14.866: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-04 11:42:14.866: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-04 11:42:14.866: E/AndroidRuntime(552):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Here relative layout is a part of your Activity layout, not of Fragment layout. so when you say `rl1 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);`, will return `null`...

Comment: okk so what should i do now to make it run??

Comment: its not working  the error is same

Answer (score 0):

Your view is

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment, null);

not activity_main.xml   where your relative_layout is.

does your menu_fragment has component of btnAdd and relative_layout, if not it will crash

Can you post menu_fragment.xml?

Comment: i am going to add the fragment xml

Comment: so obviously you do not have id :relative_layout in your menu_fragment.xml, try add one. Do not get confuse, you are now in menu_fragment as view. Not activity_main

Comment: have you seen the picture which i have posted??

Comment: @hanish  you mean your menu_fragment.xml.  Yes. I saw

Comment: i want to add the button in relative layout ,when i click on the button in fragment

Comment: the picture i have posted is the main activity which contain the fragment and the relative layout

Comment: try my answer below which add a relative layout to your menu_fragment to avoid crashing when compiler can't find id relative_layout in your menu_fragment.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
 LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater)getContext().
                              getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, parent, false);
 btnAddButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    rl1 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
```

Comment: will you please elaborate it??

Answer (score 0):

Try modify your menu_fragment.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFD3D3D3"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it will add the button in the fragment which is not my requirement
i want to show it on the right side which is my realtive layout in the main activity

Comment: hm..ok in that case you need to do the adding of button in your activity not your fragment class use callback, when you click the add button in your fragment. trigger callback function in your activity class, add the button there.

Comment: i have tried it but nothing is happening on the click

Comment: yes i called AddButton(v);
in the click listener of add button in fragment class after applying your code whereever you had suggested

Comment: Did you implement call back, onAttach(Activity activity) similar as answer i posted.  Use Log to make sure you able to call the AddButtonInActivityClass from your fragment first.

Comment: yes but i am getting eror in  mCallback = (OnFragmentChangedListener)

Multiple markers at this line
 - mCallback cannot be resolved to a variable
 - mCallback cannot be resolved to a variable
 - OnFragmentChangedListener cannot be resolved 
  to a type

Comment: Yes, it seems correct, you need to fix those compilation error since implements callback there are many steps, without one, you can't compile.   Your activity need implements <Fragment Name>.Callbacks

Comment: confussed totally dude

Comment: I feel the same when I first use callback, once you know it, it will be easy to do. The example I used to learn is more complicated. If you want, here it is.   http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/android/6996-fragment-and-activity-working-together.html?start=3

Comment: The main point is how to get your fragment to call one of the function in activity. ie. a click of button in fragment will trigger the activity class to do something. Good luck

Comment: you able to call a function in activity from your fragment yet?

Comment: not yet still trying actually i had switched to the other module that part is done so now i will try to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Try Tis code it wil work, i hv already tested it in my system

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater)getContext().
                                  getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment, parent, false)
        btnAddButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        rl1 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
        btnAddButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Button btn = new Button(getActivity());
                btn.setText("Button");
                rl1.addView(btn);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your menu_fragment

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="AddButton"
    android:text="Button" />
```

In your fragment class

```
private Callbacks mCallbacks;
public interface Callbacks {
        //Callback for when button clicked.
        public void AddButtonInActivityClass();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);       

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (OnFragmentChangedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

public AddButton(View v){
((Callbacks) getActivity()).AddButtonInActivityClass();
}
```

Then inside your activity class

```
@Override
public void AddButtonInActivityClass() {
//Here is where you start to add your button

//only at the activity which inflate activity_main can call relative_layout
rl1 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);


  Button btn = new Button(this);
  btn.setText("Button");
  rl1.addView(btn);
```

}